# Emit not working calling from child in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Output("analyze") analyze: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
var res=this.analyze.emit(template[i].replace(/_/g, ' '),ans[i]);
```

Calling from parent component

```
<app-child [analyze]="analyze"></app-child>
```

this is the method in parent component

```
analyze(param1,param2)
      {
```

where param1 and param2 accepts array type value.

```
for(var k=0;k<res.length;k++)
```

I have tried with this way also

```
 @Output("analyze") analyze: EventEmitter<{param1: any, param2: any}> = new EventEmitter();
    var res=this.analyze.emit({param1: template[i].replace(/_/g, ' '), param2: ans[i]});
```

[image]

this is also not working getting error, Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong here change square [] with parenthesis

```
<app-child (analyze)="analyze($event)"></app-child>
```

Also pass object instead of two params in emit

@user3653474

why

```
var res = this.answer.emit({ Res: '', Ans: '' });
console.log(res.length);
```

emit do not return anything so the error you are getting is obvious

Comment: Thanks when i use this `var res=this.analyze.emit(template[i].replace(/_/g, ' '),ans[i]);` i get error expected 0 or 1 argument but i have to pass two argument

Comment: @user3653474 yes so pass object instead of two params like this.analyze.emit({param1: template[i].replace(/_/g, ' '), param2: ans[i]});

Comment: Cannot get result length `res.length` Property 'length' does not exist on type void

Comment: @user3653474 what does res hold.

Comment: `res` is the value returned from the parent function its type is array this is working on main component but when i'm trying to call it from child component then getting this error

Comment: @user3653474 please share stack blitz link with sample code

Comment: Code I have created this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcgxgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html but here are some errors, i want to call parent method from child component here it is `slide1.component` that will be called on `plusSlides` function

Comment: Error is because your function is not consistent in app.component.ts as well there shoud be only 1 param for answer fucntion   answer(result) {}

Comment: If i remove this `(answer)="answer($event)"` where i'm passing it to child element then there is no error what change i have to make?

Comment: I have added screeshot also of the error that i'm getting, can you please check